# Clickable stack trace from Visual Studio's Output pane?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stack-trace, clickable

A stack trace has appeared in the Output pane of my VS2010.  Is there an extension/etc that will make that stack trace clickable (to navigate to the relevant code)?

Comment: If you have control over how the file references are printed to the output window, you can write them in such a way that it'll just work (the output window will handle the linking).  If not, you could write an extension to do it, but it really depends on what the format is.